# Why can't tuxboot and ubuntu play well together?

Tags: backup

I'm trying to get clonezilla to run off of a usb stick, and it seems that the right way to do that is via tuxboot.

Tuxboot is not compilable on ubuntu.  I used git to get it from the repository, and then when I run the 'install' script (because building it is apparently not allowed, since the build script just tries to install windows things).  Qmake-linux wants my qmake executable to be in the same directory as the stuff I pulled down, and let's just say that if there's a way to do this easily, I ain't seein' it.

So then I download the linux file, the most recent of which is tuxboot-linux-25.  Try to run it, get a failure that libpng12.so.0 isn't found.  OK, then I go to install that via the instructions I found on the web but firefox seems to have already deleted from my history (yay!)

Then I add the /usr/local/lib directory to ldconfig via emacs (had to install that too, of course):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=369848

I still get the errors that libpng12.so.0 cannot be opened because 'No such file or directory'.  ldconfig -p | grep libpng shows that the library is there, but it still doesn't seem to be findable.  What to do next?

(for the record, doing this in windows is painless-- download, click, and it's done.  But I'm trying to be all linuxy and get away from Windows for this...)

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded `tuxboot` myself and had no problem to get it running in Ubuntu 10.04. You do not need to build it from source, you can download the `*.bin` file from the homepage.

After that, open a terminal and navigate to the folder where `tuxboot` is, in my case this was `~/Downloads`. Execute it with:

```
sudo chmod +x tuxboot-linux-25-64bit
```

Replace `tuxboot-linux-25-64bit` with the appropriate file name in case of different version (like 32-bit). After that run it with:

```
./tuxboot-linux-25-64bit
```

Comment: Yeah.  The problem there is that the libpng12.so isn't found in 11.10.  Could this be a difference in the Ubuntu versions?  I'm not building tuxboot from source, I'm building libpng from source.

Comment: Could be a version thing, sure. I literally just did what I wrote in my answer and it worked. I misunderstood, however, and thought you are not using the pre-build package

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install `tuxboot` from the [ppa:thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot](https://launchpad.net/~thomas.tsai/+archive/ubuntu-tuxboot) PPA. Thus you don't need to compile it or to use the pre-compiled binaries from the project website.